# views views_handler_field_date broken/handler

Tags: 7, views

I have a HOOK_views_data() hook and everything in it works except my timestamp field.  It's pretty much stolen from webform.

Except views always complains about a broken/missing handler for this field (just this one - 'views_handler_field_date').

```
// Submitted timestamp.
$data['nodelog_report_submission']['submitted'] = array(
  'title' => t('Submitted'),
  'help' => t('The date this submission was submitted.'),
  'field' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date',
    'click sortable' => TRUE,
  ),
  'filter' => array(
    'title' => t('Submitted'),
    'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_date',
  ),
  'sort' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
  ),
  'argument' => array(
    'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_date',
  ),
);
```

I'm pulling my hair out with this one.  Anyone out there that can save me from baldness?